# Is this statement equivalent to AC?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, axiom-of-choice

Let $Frege(X)$ be the set of all equivalence classes of subsets of $X$ under equivalence relation *bijection*. formally:

$Frege(X)= \{\{Y \subseteq X: |Y|=|Z|\}: Z \subseteq X \}$

Where $||$ is cardinality function defined after [Scott's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick).

My question is about the following statement:

$\forall X: |Frege(X)| \leq |X|+1$

> Is it equivalent to the axiom of choice over the rest of axioms of $\sf ZF$?

> More precisely can $\sf ZF$ plus the above statement prove the axiom of choice?

Afternote: To spell the above without invoking Scott's cardinality just replace $|Y|=|Z|$ by $\exists f(f: Y \to Z \land f \text{ is a bijection})$, and replace $|Frege(X)| \leq |X| + 1$ by $\exists g (g: Frege(X) \to X \cup \{X\} \land g \text{ is an injection})$

Comment: I think invoking Scott cardinality just makes this messier: you're just asking about the principle "For all $X$ there is an injection from $\{$subsets of $X$ modulo bijectability$\}$ to $X\sqcup\{*\}$," right?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, yes definitely you can speak about them in terms in injections, etc... but it burns down to the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I only mentioned that since some readers might not be familiar with the notion of Scott cardinality.

Comment: OK, I've edited the post. Thanks!